# Show\Hide AdMob from within a Surfaceview

Tags: android, interface, callback, admob, surfaceview

I have admob implemented into my game, but my game uses a surfaceview to display the graphics.

How would I "access" The AdMob View from within the Surface view?

**EDIT 2:**

Tried to implement callbacks:

**MainActivity.class**

```
interface AdMobInterface {
public void HideAd();
public void ShowAd();
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener {

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    engine = new Engine(this);
    layout.addView(engine);

    if(engine.IsDemoVersion) {
        SetupAdMob();
    }

    setContentView(layout);

}


public void ShowAd() {
         ///Execute this from Engine.class
}

public void HideAd() {
          ///Execute this from Engine.class 
}

private void SetupAdMob() {
    String AdMobPublisherID = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMobPublisherID);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adView, params);
    layout.bringChildToFront(layout.getChildAt(1));
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}


}
```

**Engine.class**

```
  public class Engine extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener, AdMobInterface {

AdMobInterface AdMob;

  public Engine(Context context, AdMobInterface admob) {
    super(context);


   AdMob = admob;

 }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` and show the the add on top of the surface view. Something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <AdView id="@+id/ad" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then all you need to do is find the AdView by ID and remove it from the parent layout.

```
View adView = findViewById(R.id.ad);
FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
root.removeView(adView);
```

It is best to do this from inside the activity, there is no need for your 'Engine' to know about ads or layouts.

Comment: but the game takes place inside the 'engine' - I can't click a "button" object i made on the screen to toggle the ads?

this.ContentViewContainer.HideAd(); ...something like that

Comment: Pass a callback interface to your Engine and have it call it when needed. Your base activity will implement the interface and perform the actual adding/removing.

Comment: Any tips on how to "pass a callbck interface"?
Found this:http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

Tried implementing it to no avail

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Looks like you are on the right track: you need to implement `HideAd()` in your activity, and call it via the interface you have passed to `Engine` when appropriate. Just make sure it's called on the UI thread.

Comment: it doesn't do anything, I activate the ShowAd from inside the Engine class and the code in the Activity is not executed

Besides "implementing the interface" do I have to pass a variable to the Engine when it is created? if so how do I pass it? you can't use an interface like a variable

Comment: You need a good Java book before you proceed with this. You _can_ use an interface as a variable, and your Engine class does not have to implement the `AdMobInterface`, your activity class already does. All you really need to call from inside `Engine` is `AdMob.HideAd()`. If the implementation in the activity is correct, the ad will be hidden. Use your debugger to figure exactly what is being called (or not).

Comment: okay, the Engine CLass can accept an interface as a variable, but do I create an instance of the AdMobInterface in the MainActivity class? - I realize my understanding of interfaces isn't complete, but all I want to do is Fire a method from a "parent" class in a "child" class - what do I have to "feed" to the new Engine() variable I assign to the SetCOntentView in the MainActivity class?

Comment: Since your `MainActivity implements AdListener`, you can just pass `this` to `Engine`. You don't have to create a separate instance.